# Getting column names while looping through a data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

Im using R to go through a CSV file and check the correlation of each column of data against all the others.

```
for(i in myData){
    for(n in myData){
        pcc = cor.test(i, n, method="pearson")
        corr <- pcc$estimate
        pval <- pcc$p.value
        if(corr > .45 && pval < .05){
            print(colnames(myData)[i])
            print(colnames(myData)[n])
            print (corr)
         }
     }
}
```

I'm trying to get my output to be column name of i, column name of n, and the correlation. Instead I get every column name, every column name, and the correlation.

I'm fairly new to R and data frames so any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: There is some confusion about what i and n are. When you write `pcc = cor.test(i, n, method="pearson")`  you are treating them as columns of myData,  but when you write `print(colnames(myData)[i])` and `print(colnames(myData)[n])`  you are treating them like they are indices

Comment: In the first pass of your loops, `i` is assigned the first column of the data.frame as a full vector; so is `n`; so your first `cor.test` call is effectively `cor.test(myData[,1], myData[,1], method="pearson")`. This should be fine for your `pcc` value. However, `colnames(myData)[i]` does not make sense, since it is not retrieving the "nth" name in the vector of column names. Perhaps `for (i in seq_along(myData))` (same for `n`) and `cor.test(myData[,i], myData[,n], ...)` would be better?

Comment: @r2evans your advice did the trick, much appreciated. If you want to write it as an answer, I can check it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A verbatim fix of your code is:

```
for (i in seq_along(myData)){
    for(n in seq_along(myData)){
        pcc = cor.test(myData[,i], myData[,n], method="pearson")
        corr <- pcc$estimate
        pval <- pcc$p.value
        if(corr > .45 && pval < .05){
            print(colnames(myData)[i])
            print(colnames(myData)[n])
            print (corr)
         }
     }
}
```

But you aren't saving any of this, instead just printing it to the console. An alternate approach:

```
myData <- mtcars # since I don't have your data

eg <- expand.grid(c1 = colnames(myData), c2 = colnames(myData), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
eg <- eg[with(eg, c1 != c2),]
```

This is now a complete pair-wise list of column names:

```
head(eg)
#     c1  c2
# 2  cyl mpg
# 3 disp mpg
# 4   hp mpg
# 5 drat mpg
# 6   wt mpg
# 7 qsec mpg
```

The majority of the work. Unfortunately, an often-confusing thing about using `sapply` when a vector is returned is that it requires `t`ransposing to put it back inline with the perception of expected dimensions.

```
res <- t(sapply(seq_len(nrow(eg)), function(i) {
  pcc <- cor.test(myData[[eg$c1[i]]], myData[[eg$c2[i]]], method = "pearson")
  c(pcc$estimate, pcc$p.value)
}))
colnames(res) <- c("estimate", "p.value")
out <- cbind(eg, res)
```

This stores everything, which you don't need in the long run, but you can easily go back and see everything.

```
head(out)
#     c1  c2   estimate      p.value
# 2  cyl mpg -0.8521620 6.112687e-10
# 3 disp mpg -0.8475514 9.380327e-10
# 4   hp mpg -0.7761684 1.787835e-07
# 5 drat mpg  0.6811719 1.776240e-05
# 6   wt mpg -0.8676594 1.293959e-10
# 7 qsec mpg  0.4186840 1.708199e-02
```

From here, you can filter and output.

```
head(out[ out$estimate > 0.45 & out$p.value < 0.05, ])
#      c1  c2  estimate      p.value
# 5  drat mpg 0.6811719 1.776240e-05
# 8    vs mpg 0.6640389 3.415937e-05
# 9    am mpg 0.5998324 2.850207e-04
# 10 gear mpg 0.4802848 5.400948e-03
# 14 disp cyl 0.9020329 1.802838e-12
# 15   hp cyl 0.8324475 3.477861e-09
```

(BTW: not sure if it is intentional, but if you only want "strong correlation" whether positive *or negative*, you should change it to:

```
out[ abs(out$estimate) > 0.45 & out$p.value < 0.05, ]
```